# Ceinture et bretelles

Tags: expressions

Bonjour :)

Comment traduiriez-vous en anglais l'expression « avec ceinture et bretelles » (avec beaucoup de précautions redondantes) ?

How would you say in english something very close from "avec ceinture et bretelles" (litterally "with belt and suspenders", with redundant precaustions).

Comment: Intéressante question, même si a priori ce n'est pas le lieu pour les traductions *fr → en*. Cela dit, je n'ai trouvé aucun équivalent français après une recherche sommaire. Dans deux jours, le concours de néologismes commence...

Comment: En passant, cette variante entendue parfois pour accentuer encore l'idée de sur-vérification : *Ceintures, bretelles, parachute*

Comment: Ce site a pour objet le français, et n'accepte donc que les questions de traduction *vers* le français. Cette question aurait cependant sa place sur [English Language and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'd literally say "belt and suspenders". See for example https://www.google.com/search?q=belt%20and%20suspenders%20redundancy ... I've heard it used in telecom engineering, e.g. have mains power for a telephone exchange, and a backup generator in the exchange in case the mains power fails, and another portable backup generator on a truck outside in case the primary backup generator fails.

Comment: Cette expression est un calque de l'anglais que certains ne prennent même pas la peine de traduire.